# Qt5: date format MMM, in Spanish, remove point

Tags: date, localization, qt5, date-format

In Qt5, the `MMM` format, which displays the month name in a short format (e.g., "Dec" instead of "12" or "December"), when using it for the Spanish locale, shows the abbreviated month name with a dot at the end, for example, for, "25th December 2016", in `MMM/dd/yyyy` format, shows "Dic./25/2016".

The problem is when editing. For displaying a date, it's ok, since it's what the Spanish rules say, but it isn't suitable for editing. I'm forced to position the cursor just after the point, at the end of the month part, to delete the point, and then, the rest of the month name. If I try to put the cursor just before the point, to edit just the month name part, the field is in "read-only" mode. I can't not remove anything, unless I remove everything from the very right of the line and back, character to character (or just selecting the whole month part and remove everything).

Besides, the point is not autocompleted. So, if the user writes the new month forgetting the dot, the edition is rejected and fall backs to the original value.

Taking all of it into account, editing a `QDateEdit` is a bit cumbersome (in Spanish).

I don't know if it is the built-in `QDateEdit` behaviour, or internally it is using a `QRegExpValidator`, but in that case, I don't know what it's the regexp expression, to personalize it from it.

In short, how can I "solved" it? (the cumbersome edition; it's ok for me both, removing the dot, or changing the validation).

Answer (score 1):

The Qt 5 behavior is correct and there's nothing Qt can do (or should do). The only correct and acceptable short name of December in a es_ES locale is "dic.", trailing dot included. That's what CLDR says:

- http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/30/summary/es.html#1636
- http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/30/verify/dates/es.html

Comment: Yes, I know that's what the rules of the spanish lang say. I only say that that rule isn't suitable for editing (but it's ok for displaying a date). The `QDateEdit` doesn't allow me, for example, to delete characters before the point. If I try to edit the month name, positioning the cursor just before the point to just edit the month name, I can't; the month field is in read-only mode unless I start the edition deleting the point and then, the month name (and the point isn't autocompleted either, so, it must be written as well).

Comment: Not allow editing of substring of the month's name could indeed be a QDateTimeEdit limitation, and as such, deserve a bug report. Not autocompleting the trailing dot could also be a different feature request (try to autocomplete the typed prefix, I guess). How about making the users type the month number, not its name? :p

Comment: The problem with changing the month from string to number, is that, in spanish, the "day" part appears before the "month" part (in english, the natural date order is reversed). So, if the user wants to change "30/11/2016" by "31/12/2016", he can change "30" by "31", and then "11" to "12", but since november has 30 days, the edition is rejected and the month must be edited first. My solution was to change the month/day order, as in english. But since starting by a month is counter-intuitive in Spain, I show the month as a string, which now introduces a edition a bit cumbersome.

Comment: "which now introduces a edition a bit cumbersome", and I must add: " in Qt5, because of the damned dot (which didn't appear in Qt4)". By the way, I'have changed the wording of my question, to make more explicit my problem.

Comment: The fact is, Qt 4 behavior was technically wrong, as CLDR says otherwise, and that's the autorithative source. Checking whether you need `day/month/year` or `month/year/date` for a given locale is extremely easy, just use `QLocale::dateTimeFormat(NarrowFormat)`, and it will return the right formatting string (to be applied on the edit). For `es_ES` it will return `d/M/yy H:mm`. (Note how it also tells you if you should left pad the days/months with 0s, and how many digits for the year, and so on).